# Redirect from docroot to an external url in glassfish

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I've googled around and only found solution where they suggest putting an apache httpd in front of glassfish. Sure, that works.

But what if I do not wish to/cannot put any thing in front of glassfish?

Without using the index.jsp in the docroot of the domain to have something like:

```
<%
    String redirectURL = "https://stackoverflow.com/";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>
```

Can I make browser to be redirected when I point it to: http://my.glassfish.domain/ ?

To provide a little bit more details:

I tried adding a property to the vitual server as:
redirect_1 from=/ url=https://stackoverflow.com/
But that make everything to be redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/, eg. http://my.glassfish.domain/myapp redirects to https://stackoverflow.com/ while all I want was http://my.glassfish.domain/ to be redirected to https://stackoverflow.com/

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can use [UrlRweriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) to  redirect users according to defined mappings. [Here](http://urlrewritefilter.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/doc/manual/3.2/guide.html) are some examples

Comment: Will need to do some investigation, but thanks for pointing the UrlRewriteFilter. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I think the solution you dismiss is actually the 'best'...

Write a jsp in the docroot for the server.

If you really have to do something fancier, due to complications that you haven't described, you may want to try creating a new DefaultServer.  Look in your domain-dir/config/default-web.xml.

You may want to look at the [code of the DefaultServer that ships with GlassFish Server 3](http://fisheye5.cenqua.com/browse/glassfish/appserv-webtier/src/java/org/apache/catalina/servlets/DefaultServlet.java#r1.17) as a guide.

Answer (score 0):

Modify the DNS mapping for the given URL in your DNS Server (/etc/host on your local machine) . May not be a feasible solution for you - but it does the work of directing the user.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but as you guessed, it is not feasible for us. :(

Answer (score 0):

No you can not. When a request comes to your server, there should be a page (HTML/JSP/Servlet) to process that page. That page should do whatever you wanted to do.

So you must create a HTML / JSP / Servlet.

Hope this helps.