# GlassFish redirect www to non-www domain

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish

Is it possible to redirect users from `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`?
I'm running GlassFish 3.1.1 with JSF/EJB app in root context (/).
It would be also nice to keep context path/params:

```
www.domain.com/subpage/title/ -> domain.com/subpage/title/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Redirect from docroot to an external url in glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808101/redirect-from-docroot-to-an-external-url-in-glassfish) discusses three ways to do this - every single one requires some extra efforts:

1. Modify the DNS mapping in your DNS server;
2. Use [UrlRewriteFilter](http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/); or
3. Put a web server - like apache httpd - in front of glassfish.